# `ClassName.constants` returning empty array in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lazy-loading, constants

I'm working on a Rails 3 app, and I've got a hierarchy of classes in my `lib` folder, e.g.:

```
lib
├── assets
├── tasks
│   └── import.rake
└── importer
    ├── base.rb
    └── source
        ├── facebook.rb
        ├── google.rb
        └── twitter.rb
```

I've updated `config/application.rb` to include this line:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Then inside of `Importer::Base`, I have an instance method that attempts to load all classes in the `Provider` module, e.g.:

```
Importer::Source.constants.each do |class_name|
  Importer::Source.const_get(class_name).process
end
```

The three classes in `lib/importer/base` have a class hierarchy similar to:

```
module Importer
  module Source
    class Facebook
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

When I call this method, `Importer::Source.constants` ends up returning an empty array.  The classes appear to be lazy-loaded properly if I reference them by name directly, but they are not accessible in the `constants` call.  How can I fix this?

Comment: you should require the files manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @apneadiving's suggestion, I was able to fix this by adding this line to the beginning of my `base.rb` file:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('lib/importer/source/**/*.rb')].each(&method(:require))
```

Comment: btw `require_dependency` is a way to have your classes reloaded in dev mode, better than a mere `require`